# Remove adjacent duplicate substrings

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to remove duplicate adjacent substrings of `k` length, where `k` refers to the word count. The code should work in a recursive fashion starting from

k = 1 word 
upto
k = number of words in the string

For example,

> i sat down to write **an article an article** this morning but found that **i i** could make no progress

becomes

> i sat down to write **an article** this morning but found that **i** could make no progress

How do I achieve this? I can achieve `1` length adjacent substring removal by:

```
str.chunk{|n| n}.map(&:first)
```

Comment: This is very complex (if unresolvable in general) task that deserved a PhD thesis not SO question. For starters: what should be removed from **"I like to move it move it, I like to move it move it"**?

Comment: In this case, it should work recursively, i.e.

In 1st Iteration -

"I like to move it move it"

In 2nd iteration -

"I like to move it"

Comment: Your question is not clear. For the substring `" an article"` to be removed, `k` should be 11. For the substring `" i"` to be removed, `k` should be 2. What is the logic behind that removes them both at the same time?

Comment: @sawa - here 'k' refers to a word and not a character, and it works in a recursive fashion so, 'k' starts with 1 and goes uptill the length of number of words in the string.

Comment: You have not mentioned that at all in the question. Specify everything to make your question comprehensible.

Comment: Thanks sawa, have updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = "i sat down to write an article an article this morning but found that i i could make no progress"

max = s.scan(/\S+/).length
# => 20
1.upto(max).each_with_object(s) do
  |n, s| s.gsub!(/((?:\b\s*\S+){#{n}})\1/, '\1')
end
# => "i sat down to write an article this morning but found that i could make no progress"
```

By the way,

```
"I like to move it move it, I like to move it move it"
```

will result in:

```
"I like to move it, I like to move it"
```

not:

```
"I like to move it"
```

as you mentioned in the comment because there is no adjacent repetition 
beyond the string above (watch out for the comma and the space).

Comment: Nice. It would be great if you could explain a little more about how the regex works in your code.

Comment: **s.gsub(/((?:\b\s*\S+)+)\1/, '\1')** works well without the iteration.

Comment: Rajat, `'a a b a a b'.gsub(/((?:\b\s*\S+)+)\1/, '\1')
=> "a a b a b"`, whereas `"a b"` is desired.

Comment: Your code clearly worked at one point but evidently [a funny thing happened on your way to the forum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Funny_Thing_Happened_on_the_Way_to_the_Forum_(film)).. Now it return the original string.

Comment: I became aware of the problem at some point, but did not have access here til now. It was due to having `n` without interpolation syntax. I have fixed it now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the string contains no white spaces other than spaces (no tabs, newlines, line feeds, form feeds, etc.) and that words are either separated by one space, or if separated by multiple spaces, the string returned may contain only one space between words. (There is a work-around to the latter, but it is not central to the question.)

```
def remove_repeats(str)
  s = str.squeeze(' ')
  s.insert(0, ' ')
  change = ''
  until change.nil?
    change = s.gsub!(/(?:((?: \S+)+))\1/, '\1')
  end
  s[1..-1]
end

remove_repeats 'a a b a a b'              #=> "a b"
remove_repeats 'a a b c a a b c d'        #=> "a b c d"
remove_repeats ' c a a b a a b d a a b e' #=> " c a b d a b e"
remove_repeats 'aa a bb bb b'             #=> "aa a bb b"
remove_repeats 'a b c d e f'              #=> "a b c d e f"
remove_repeats ''                         #=> ""
```

The regular expression reads as follows: "For any string that consists of  a space followed by a string of non-spaces, repeat that string one or more times and save the result in capture group 1. Match the contents of the capture group one or more times, followed by the contents of the capture group.  If `gsub!` makes at least one replacement, `s` is updated; else `gsub!` returns `nil`. Note that, before replacing text, I inserted a space at the beginning of the string then removed it after al replacements were complete.

`/((?: \S+)+)\1/` also works for the examples above, but may require more iterations to obtain a solution.

I have not been able to prove this works in all cases. I invite readers to offer a proof that it does or a counterexample.